# What are the Antimalware Protected Process Light (AM-PPL) dll loading requirements?

Tags: windows, security, windows-defender, antimalware

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services- "any non-Windows DLLs that get loaded into the protected process must be signed with an appropriate certificate."

What are the conditions for a DLL to be considered "non-Windows"? In other words, what is a "Windows" dll.

I know for a fact that msmpeng.exe, an AM-PPL process will load C:\Windows\System32\slc.dll, an unsigned dll. Why is that permitted?

Any information is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be that it means *DLLs that are not a part of the Windows OS itself*.

Comment: As far as slc.dll, it's part of the Windows OS and protected, which means it isn't required by the OS to be signed.

Comment: But what does it mean to be a part of the OS? Is there a hardcoded list in the Kernel? Is it based on the file path? If it is not signed, what guarantees the file has not been tampered with?

Comment: Being  part of the OS means officially distributed by MS as part of the OS. Yes, there is an internal list of system files, and if you try to replace or remove them Windows will replace them with the true copy. I would imagine that there is an internal code that identifies the file, as well as a checksum that must match. Part of the OS does not mean strictly the kernel - other files are included as well, such as User32.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows DLL is a DLL shipped with Windows and signed by a chain that Microsoft defines as Windows. The leaf certificate is typically named something along the lines of "Microsoft Windows". This is different from a file shipped with MS Office etc. I can't rule out there being a file list involved somehow as well. I believe some Windows components like rundll32.exe and other host components are not fully trusted in all scenarios because they load external code.

slc.dll, like 99.999% of PE files shipped with Windows today, is signed. It is catalog signed, not with a embedded certificate. Use SigCheck to verify.

Comment: That's the knowledge I was missing @Anders. I didn't know about catalog signing. Now the world makes sense again!

Thanks,